# Enums in Scala with multiple constructor parameters

Tags: scala, enums

I am writing my first large Scala program. In the Java equivalent, I have an enum that contains labels and tooltips for my UI controls:

```
public enum ControlText {
  CANCEL_BUTTON("Cancel", "Cancel the changes and dismiss the dialog"),
  OK_BUTTON("OK", "Save the changes and dismiss the dialog"),
  // ...
  ;

  private final String controlText;
  private final String toolTipText;

  ControlText(String controlText, String toolTipText) {
    this.controlText = controlText;
    this.toolTipText = toolTipText;
  }

  public String getControlText() { return controlText; }
  public String getToolTipText() { return toolTipText; }
}
```

Never mind the wisdom of using enums for this. There are other places that I want to do similar things.

How can I do this in Scala using scala.Enumeration? The Enumeration.Value class takes only one String as a parameter. Do I need to subclass it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do this which matches how enums are used:

```
sealed abstract class ControlTextBase
case class ControlText(controlText: String, toolTipText: String)
object OkButton extends ControlText("OK", "Save changes and dismiss")
object CancelButton extends ControlText("Cancel", "Bail!")
```

Comment: I use this idiom too for all the enumerated types.

Comment: Better than my answer,k that's for sure

Comment: It is better to have an `sealed abstract class` as parent, then the case classes or objects desired, and then, if you want specific instances of a case class, _normal_ objects instead of case objects.

Comment: Edited to reflect my understanding of Daniel Sobral's comment.  Daniel, what is the benefit of having the ControlTextBase abstract class here?  Is it just for flexibility?

Comment: I'm beginning with Scala but in this state I would say it lacks something: "ControlText" should extends "ControlTextBase", yes or no ?

Comment: you could delete the first line and make ControlText the sealed abstract class

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to propose the following workaround for the issue:

```
object ControlText extends Enumeration {

  type ControlText = ControlTextValue

  case class ControlTextValue(controlText: String, toolTipText: String) extends Val(controlText)

  val CANCEL_BUTTON = ControlTextInternalValue("Cancel", "Cancel the changes and dismiss the dialog")
  val OK_BUTTON = ControlTextInternalValue("OK", "Save the changes and dismiss the dialog")

  protected final def ControlTextInternalValue(controlText: String, toolTipText: String): ControlTextValue = {
    ControlTextValue(controlText, toolTipText)
  }    
}
```

Now you can use `ControlText` as Java enum:

```
val c: ControlText
c.toolTipText
```

The only a little bad smell is to get enum object by `withName` or `apply` methods. You have to do a cast:

```
val c: ControlText = ControlText.withName(name).asInstanceOf[ControlText]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Mitch's answer, if you find that the sealed behaviour is not restrictive enough in limiting subclassed instances to the file where the base class is defined, you can use an object (module) definition like this:

```
object ControlTexts {
  sealed abstract class ControlTextBase

  case class ControlText private[ControlTexts] (controlText: String, 
                                                toolTipText: String)
          extends ControlTextBase

  object OkButton     extends ControlText("OK", "Save changes and dismiss")
  object CancelButton extends ControlText("Cancel", "Bail!")
}
```

which obviously limits further instantiation of ControlText instances. The sealed keyword is still important in helping detect missing cases in pattern matching.